# facebook native ap is not launched in fb login in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I have implemented facebook api in my app to support facebook login. When I tap the facebook button then it launches a safari it does not redirect to my native facebook app. I have installed facebook app & logged in.

**I have used following code**
// Do any additional setup after

```
 FBSDKLoginButton *loginButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];
    loginButton.delegate=self;
    loginButton.readPermissions =
    @[@"email", @"user_friends"];
    [self.view addSubview:loginButton];
```

How can I launch the fb native app?

**EDIT:**
**AppDelegate code**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

{
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                          openURL:url
                                                sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                       annotation:annotation
            ];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

@end
```

Comment: Did you forget to add the `FacebookAppID` and `FacebookDisplayName` to your plist?

Comment: No i added it in plist file

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing this in your appdelegate.m ?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
     annotation:(id)annotation {
return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                      openURL:url
                                            sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                   annotation:annotation];
}
```

Comment: I have added this code snippet but still it is not working.@kriOS